# find the range of a function as a domain

Tags: functions

In my mathematics guide for University, I came across this example. I do not fully understand the method used to acquire the range for the function defined.

*p.s. apologies for the generic title, I am not even sure what the correct title should be*

[image: Problem function]

Answer (score 1):

The range of a function is the same as the domain of the function's inverse (if the inverse exists).

In the attachment they are finding the inverse of the function $\alpha$ and the finding the inverse's domain.

Comment: thanks for the response, this does not answer my question/I do not understand you answer.

Comment: Well, let's go a step at a time.  Do you know what inverse functions are?

Comment: I will be covering that in about an hour, after I get my head around this section :p. This section is covering the basics of onto/surjective and one-to-one functions. I did inverse functions a long time ago, about a year and a bit. but ever so brielfy that I barely remember it. so no! :p

Comment: Ah.  Well, nevermind then.  Lol.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary $\;w\in\Bbb Q\;$ and check when there exists $\;a\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{1\}\;$ with $\;\alpha(a)=w\;$ :

$$\alpha(a)=w\iff \frac{2a-3}{a-1}=w\iff2a-3=aw-w\iff$$

$$(2-w)a=3-w\stackrel{\text{we require}\, w\neq 2}\iff a=\frac{3-w}{2-w}$$

and thus Im$\,(\alpha)=\Bbb Q\setminus\{2\}\;$ , otherwise you cannot get $\;a\;$ as a function of $\;w\;$ in the last step above.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it. but may I add, it takes me a while to understand mathematics, and its concepts. Could I ask that you guide me through this example. To start off, 1. is there any significance t using the alpha symbol, or can I just simply replace this with a 'f' to make understanding easier (for me it helps)? 2. I understand that the domain is defined by Q (rational n) excluding {1} where it is not defined. What I do not understand: q E Q = { x/y : ...}. I understand that in defining a set, one would use z E R{(x;y): x,y E Z...}, but what is with the x/y?

Comment: why not just x, or just y. why is x being divided by y?

Comment: 1.- You can use $\;f\;$ . 2.- I'd advice to forget, at least as a first step towards understanding, the $\;Q=\{...;$ and all that: this is only the formal definition of the rational numbers, that are *quotients* of integer numbers and the denominator non-zero. Just try to focus first in understanding why we **have to** have $\;a\neq2\;$

Comment: If I understand this correctly then, in the line beneath "Say q = 3/4", where we plugin the q=3/4. q would generally speaking be the "y", and "a" be the "x"? if so. then " = 'alpha'  ( 9/5 )" can be rewritten as "y = 9/5 "?

Comment: i think i got it, so in terms of (x;y) = (9/5;3/4) based on the fact that q = (2a-3)/(a-1). sub in q=3/4 and solve for a, where a = 9/5. If this is the case, I understand now. I also understand that  q=2  is undefined. Why do you think was the 9/5 sub done t get 3/4. that was a big part of my confusion.